# after pthread_cancel(), pthread_join() function call hangup

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join

I have written an application, which creates a thread and runs into while loop.
In the application after spawning a thread, i have overridden the `fork()` syscall with `pthread_atfork()`.
[when `fork` is called, a `prepare` function call is called which cancels the thread and after the child process is spawned the same thread is spawned again.]

I have problem in the above logic, when the same code is compiled to different target, there is hangup in `pthread_join()`.

1. spawn a thread, which runs into while loop.(i have added cancel state=Enabled and cancel type=asynchronous + cancellation points are also considered)
2. override `fork()` with `pthread_atfork()`.
3. when `fork()` system call is executed, prepare-function cancels the running thread with `pthread_cancel` and `pthread_join()` is applied to check the thread is terminated.

Here the problem occurs, the `pthread_join()` doesn't return.
the above behavior is observed in one particular target environment.

I have some doubt

1. `pthread_cancel()` is it safe to call?
2. with cancel state = enabled and type asynchronous, does `pthread_cancel()` cancel thread immediately?
3. Or is there any alternate way to cancel the thread?

Comment: Best to provide a [mcve]. It's a little difficult to follow exactly what you're doing and therefore to guess what might be going wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have debugged the program, what i have observed is, this hangup occurs in pthread.so 2.26 version of glibc. when the same is executed in pthread.so 2.24 or 2.23 issue is not reproducible.

Comment: @GilHamilton: Problem Statement as follows:                                                   
1) Main Program spawn  a thread say it "Threadrun_Infinite".                                          2) Call a system call pthread_atfork(kill-Threadrun_Infinite, NULL, NULL)               In the "kill-Threadrun-Infinite" you will be sending pthread_cancel to running thread i.e created in step 1 and will do a pthread_join() to confirm the thread is terminated.         3) execute sys_call fork() -> when this

Comment: @GilHamilton 3) execute sys_call fork() -> when this system call is executed, the pre-function "kill-Threadrun_infinite " is called .                                                         the problem is pthread_cancel is successful but the pthread_join() hang's up(its in a mutex wait).. this behaviour is observed in pthread.so 2.26. pleas e help??

Comment: You still have not provided a [mcve].